# clickhouse: How do I find the least date in array that is above date in another column?

Tags: clickhouse

Basically I have the table with the following data-structure:

- `id_level1`: *Int32*
- `id_level2`: *Int32*
- `event_date`: *Date*
- `arr_object_ids`: *Array of Int32* - sorted by next column
- `arr_object_dates`: *Array of Date* - sorted ascending

What I need is to have the least `object_date` that is above `event_date` for each pair of `(id_leve1, id_level2)`. How is that possible in Clickhouse?

Then I would use `arrayElement(arr_object_ids, indexOf(arr_object_dates, solution)` to get corresponding object_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT 
  id_level1,
  id_level2,
  /*arrayFirst(x -> x > event_date, arr_object_dates) least_date,*/
  arrayFirstIndex(x -> x > event_date, arr_object_dates) least_date_index,
  least_date_index = 0 ? -1 : arrayElement(arr_object_ids, least_date_index) object_id /* -1 if result not found */
FROM (
  /* emulate original table */
  SELECT 1 id_level1, 2 id_level2, '2020-01-03' event_date, 
    [4, 5, 6,7] arr_object_ids, 
    ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-11'] arr_object_dates
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id_level1, 4 id_level2, '2020-05-03' event_date, 
    [4, 5, 6,7] arr_object_ids, 
    ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-11'] arr_object_dates)
ORDER BY event_date 
/* result
┌─id_level1─┬─id_level2─┬─least_date_index─┬─object_id─┐
│         1 │         2 │                3 │         6 │
│         3 │         4 │                0 │        -1 │
└───────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┴───────────┘
*/
```